# how to convert list obj to client.PostAsJsonAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

how to convert list obj to client.PostAsJsonAsync

Class model

```
public class CheckStatusModel
{
    public int OBJID { get; set; }
    public string SUPID { get; set; }
    public string STATUSPTC { get; set; }  
    public int DATEACTIVESUP { get; set; }
}

public class CheckStatus
{
    public CheckStatusModel Data { get; set; }
    public string StatusCode { get; set; }
}
```

Sending request to find web api REST service resource using
   HttpClient**

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
     client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Baseurl);
     client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
     client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new 
     MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
     HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/RPDeployment/BIL_CFP_BOX_CHECK_STATUSPTC", checkStatusParam);
     if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
       {
            var EmpResponse = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            ListStatusPTC = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CheckStatus>>(EmpResponse);// not convert ????

       }
 }
```

EmpResponse

```
{
  "data": [**
    {
      "OBJID": 1012540462,
      "SUPID": 1041252952,
      "STATUSPTC": 1,
      "DATEACTIVESUP": 0
    }
  **],
  "StatusCode": 200
}
```

help me please ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh I see. You're trying to deserialize an object (denoted by `{` and `}`) into a list (in JSON, denoted by `[` and `]`).

You need to change your `CheckStatus` class as follows:

```
public class CheckStatus
{
    public List<CheckStatusModel> Data { get; set; } // data is an array so this needs to be some kind of collection
    public string StatusCode { get; set; }
}
```

And deserialize like so:

```
ListStatusPTC = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CheckStatus>(EmpResponse); // the JSON contains an object, so this needs to deserialize to an object. you can't deserialize to a list.
```